# Cual es el error, solo estoy creando un nuevo componente

Tags: ionic

Cree un nuevo componente con `ionic g c list-user`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-list-user',
  templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.scss'],
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
```

Y este es el archivo **app.module.ts**

```
import { ListUser } from './list-user/list-user.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ListUser],


  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at compiler.js:18685
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18683)
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu archivo app.module.ts tiene un aspecto un poco raro si te fijas falta algo de código. Este archivo suele presentar dos partes direferenciadas.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Camera,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    SocialSharing,
    File
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {}
}
```

En tu código no veo la exportación de la clase AppModule, mira a ver si añadiendolo se soluciona. Creo recordar que en ionic cada vez que generas un nuevo componente te genera un modulo por cada uno de estos componentes por lo que puede que si no sea necesario el agregarlo al AppModule global. Prueba estas dos cosas a ver, si no funcionan, muestra de nuevo el error que te muestre.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-list-user' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-list-user' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: @noseJ otra posible solución sería añadir el modulo que se te ha generado al crear el list-user (sera algo como ListUserModule) al imports de tu app module y quitándolo de declarations. *declarations: [AppComponent],imports:[ListUserModule]*. Si no funciona de esta manera intenta compartir el código y lo mirare personalmente.